# decide/solve a problem/pressing issue

Tags: meaning

I have always been under the premise that "to decide a problem" is wrong and it should be "solve a problem". But I came across "to decide a pressing issue" which was said by a native speaker. How come "decide a problem" is wrong but "decide a pressing issue" is correct?

Comment: It would really depend on the context in which the native speaker said this. You haven't provided anything for context.  Also note that native speakers can make mistakes. It could be an error, or perhaps the "pressing issue" in the speakers mind involves making a decision on several choices. A pressing issue is not necessarily the same thing as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

"Deciding a problem" typically means **identifying or recognizing that a problem exists**(in problem solving process it's considered to be the 1st step)

while "solving a problem" involves **taking actions to find a solution or resolution to that problem.**

Decide an issue implies **making a choice or settling a dispute by coming to a decision or resolution.**

Comment: Are you a native speaker?